# Вводное после тире можно закрыть запятой в присоединительном предложении?

Tags: вводные-слова

В разделе о вводных Розенталь пишет:

*Собака исчезла, — наверное, её убили.*

Можно ли часть после тире назвать присоединительным предложением и по аналогии с предложением, приведенным Розенталем в разделе о вводных:

*За оградой мелькнули гипсовые статуи, голубые павильоны, — по всей вероятности городской сад (тире перед присоединительной конструкцией).*

надо расставить знаки препинания так:

*Собака исчезла, — наверное ее убили.*

Или

Возможен ли, как в предложении о статуях, такой вариант расстановки знаков препинания:

*Собака исчезла, — наверное её убили.*

Но тогда *наверное* можно понять не как вводное, а как наречие.

Comment: doom1, Вы уже довольно давно на сайте, но почему-то забыли, что здесь принято благодарить участников за полезные ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из них галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно такое оформление:

*За оградой мелькнули гипсовые статуи, голубые павильоны, — **по всей вероятности, городской сад.***

**Пояснение**

1. Мы можем рассматривать **постановку единого знака** запятая и тире для **присоединительной конструкции**, учитывая собственные знаки в первой части, а также наличие вводного слова в присоединительном обороте.

Розенталь:§ 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении Пункт 9, примечание http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Запятая и тире могут ставиться также перед присоединительным предложением, содержащим дополнительное замечание: Посёлок Первомайский был самым старым шахтёрским посёлком в этом районе, — от него, собственно, и начался город (Ф.).

2. Вводное слово "по все вероятности" в большинстве случаев обособляется.

ПО ВСЕЙ ВЕРОЯТНОСТИ, вводное сочетание  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_531

По всей вероятности, это была какая-то разбитая немецкая часть… Ю. Бондарев, Берег.

Comment: Здесь не обязательно присоединительная конструкция. Может быть и так: *За оградой мелькнули гипсовые статуи, голубые павильоны, — по всей вероятности, [там/это] городской сад* (а не сад мелькнул).

Comment: По Розенталю присоединительные конструкции содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, а синтаксис может быть любым, то есть это может быть слово, словосочетание, оборот, предложение (любой каприз для вашей фантазии).

Comment: Аа, то автор вопроса перепутал. В правиле речь только об обороте. Тогда так: Здесь не обязательно присоединительный оборот. Может быть и так: *За оградой мелькнули гипсовые статуи, голубые павильоны, — по всей вероятности, [там/это] городской сад* (а не сад мелькнул). Тогда запятая точно нужна.

Comment: На границе простых предложений также всякое случается в зависимости от логики составителей правил. Вот пример из Справочника по пунктуации: Послал он мне крест – ЗНАЧИТ, меня он любит. А в приведенном предложении вам чем не присоединительный оборот? Содержит дополнительное замечание?.Значит, присоединительный.

Comment: В правиле речь только об обособленных оборотах, только при них запятая опускается. Говорю, что может быть не присоединительный оборот, а предложение, тогда запятая точно нужна (у Розенталя она не стоит). Предложение не оборот.

Comment: oleedd, сами разбирайтесь... Вашу мысль я уже поняла: ссылка вам не нравится. Тогда дайте  свой правильный ответ автору вопроса.

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли. Просто сообщил вам интересный факт, который обнаружил. Это не претензия.